# Vim and youcompleteme

Tags: vim, youcompleteme

Why I don't get any complete suggestions for mathematical constants from YCM?

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout<<"PI:"<<M_PI<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

After typing "M_P " in Code::Blocks I get a completion menu with entries "M_PI, M_PI_2, M_PI_4". So I can choose which one I want to use.

Why don't I have the same complete suggestions with YCM? Can YCM do the same?

(code completion for objects works very well.

```
string str="my string";
str.
```

YCM gives me here a list of all class methods for this object. Like expected)

EDIT:

OK, a few pictures. Maybe it would help (the problem is simple, probably it wasn't explained correctly)

Picture 1:
https://ibb.co/f9Xccsy

At this picture you can see that's YCM works.

Picture 2:
https://ibb.co/sJJTCjF

Here I'm using Code::Blocks as my IDE. As you see it has code-complete-function for mathematical constants.

Picture 3:
https://ibb.co/B3w2BGY

The same program as above (picture 2). But YCM doesn't give me a completion menu (like Code::Blocks does).

Do you have the same "problem" with YCM or can it be changed?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1) Add '-std=gnu11'-flag to your ".ycm_extra_conf.py"-file.

2) Force completion with `<Control> + <Space>`